# JavaScript Automated Clicking

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick, click, delay

So, here's my issue.

I need to write a script to be run in the console (or via Greasemonkey) to automate clicking of certain links to check their output.

Each time one of these links is clicked, they essentially generate an image in a flash container to the left. The goal here is to be able to automate this so that the QC technicians do not have to click each of these thumbnails themselves.

Needless to say, there needs to be a delay between each "click" event and the next so that the user can view the large image and make sure it is okay.

Here is my script thus far:

```
function pausecomp(ms) {
    ms = ms + new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms){}
} 

var itemlist, totalnumber, i;
itemlist = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
totalnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("quickNavImage").childNodes[3].firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/[0-9]* of /, ""));
for(i = 0; i < totalnumber; i = i + 1) {
    console.log(i);
    itemlist[i].childNodes[1].click();
    pausecomp(3000);
}
```

Now, totalnumber gets me the total number of thumbnails, obviously, and then itemlist is a list of get-able elements so I can access the link itself.

If I run itemlist[0].childNodes[1].click() it works just fine. Same with 1, 2, 3, etc. However, in the loop, it does nothing and it simply crashes both Firefox and IE. I don't need cross-browser capability, but I'm confused.

Comment: Can you use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for this instead?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I've never used Selenium before and I don't see why JavaScript wouldn't work. Looking at Selenium, it seems very confusing.

Comment: Download the IDE and just try to make a recording of what you want to do; that'll generate some scripts that you can play with.

Comment: It seems selenium is meant to hook into other programming environments, like C#, Python, etc. is that correct? Perhaps I am misreading this documentation, but is there any way to simply say "Open this script" in the IDE itself? I can certainly install extensions and run JavaScript on these machines, but we do not have permission to install entire programming environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People were correct with SetInterval.

For the record, here's the completed code:

```
/*global console, document, clearInterval, setInterval*/
var itemlist, totalnumber, i, counter;
i = 0;

function findmepeterpan() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Currently viewing " + (i + 1));
    itemlist[i].scrollIntoView(true);
    document.getElementById("headline").scrollIntoView(true);
    itemlist[i].style.borderColor = "red";
    itemlist[i].style.borderWidth = "thick";
    itemlist[i].childNodes[1].click();
    i = i + 1;
    if (i === totalnumber) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        console.log("And we're done! Hope you enjoyed it!");
    }
}

function keepitup() {
    "use strict";
    if (i !== 0) {
        itemlist[i - 1].style.borderColor = "transparent";
        itemlist[i - 1].style.borderWidth = "medium";
    }
    findmepeterpan();
}

itemlist = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
totalnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("quickNavImage").childNodes[3].firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/[0-9]* of /, ""), 10);
counter = setInterval(keepitup, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in JS function "setInterval(afunction, interval)" that keeps executing a given function every "interval" miliseconds (1000 = 1s).

Comment: Just as a general note: `setInterval` becomes very inaccurate rather quickly. If you actually care about timing at all, you're better off not using it. [Reference with better solutions](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/)

Comment: It becomes inaccurate when the precision is required. For code that has to be called repeatedly every second (like in this case) it's indistinguishable and in the end - irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lddubeau/YqrnM/) shows how to use `setTimeout` to work through an array. Here is the code:

```
var my_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

function step(index) {
    console.log("value of my_array at " + index + ":", my_array[index]);
    if (index < my_array.length - 1)
        setTimeout(step, 3000, index + 1);
}

setTimeout(step, 3000, 0);
```

Every 3 seconds, you'll see on the console something like:

```
value of my_array at x: v
```

where `x` is the index in the array and `v` is the corresponding value.

The problem with your code is that your `pausecomp` loop is a form of busy waiting. Let's suppose you have 10 items to go through. Your code will click an item, spin for 3 seconds, click an item, spin for 3 seconds, etc. All your clicks are doing is *queuing* events to be dispatched. However, these events are not *dispatched* until your code finishes executing. It finishes executing after all the clicks are queued and (roughly) 30 seconds (in this hypothetical scenario) have elapsed. If the number of elements is greater that's even worse.

Using `setTimeout` like above allows the JavaScript virtual machine to regain control and allows dispatching events. The documentation on `setTimeout` is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).