# Converting JavaScript clicking to Selenium

Tags: javascript, class, selenium

Apparently the task I asked about earlier ([JavaScript Automated Clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360122/javascript-automated-clicking)) is impossible in JavaScript, or at the very least extremely difficult.

However, I have found the documentation on Selenium and how to use it extremely uninviting and difficult to understand.

Perhaps someone could help me translate this code to Selenium or, alternatively, help me with particular elements I'm having difficulty with.

```
function pausecomp(ms) {
    ms = ms + new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms){}
} 

var itemlist, totalnumber, i;
itemlist = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
totalnumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("quickNavImage").childNodes[3].firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/[0-9]* of /, ""));
for(i = 0; i < totalnumber; i = i + 1) {
    console.log(i);
    itemlist[i].childNodes[1].click();
    pausecomp(3000);
}
```

Now, I know I can get elements by Class Name in Selenium, but how do I get specific child nodes?

Likewise, how do I use regex to cut out the total number of items that needs to be clicked? It is only available in text form.

And finally, how do I iterate in Selenium?

Please note, I have no available programming environments on these computers. So I cannot use Python, C#, etc. hooks unless they can be directly imported into the Selenium IDE itself. However, the documentation is difficult for me to understand, so I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: No, the task you've asked about earlier is neither impossible, nor extremely difficult. I've given you a method to do it, did you look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Please take a look at my previous linked post. I was being an idiot. I'll put the answer up there.